# "select form" does not sync with model

Tags: angularjs

This is my template:

```
<div class="form-group" 
  ng-repeat="recipeIngredient in recipes.currentRecipe._ingredients">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ingredient {{ $index + 1 }}</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10 form-inline" role="form">
    <input 
      type="text" 
      class="form-control" 
      placeholder="quantity" 
      ng-model="recipeIngredient.quantity"
    >
    <input 
      type="text" 
      class="form-control" 
      ng-model="recipeIngredient._unit"
    >
    <select 
      class="form-control" 
      ng-model="recipeIngredient._unit" 
      ng-options="unit._id for unit in units" 
    />
    <select 
      ng-model="recipeIngredient._ingredient" 
      class="form-control" 
      ng-model="recipeIngredient._ingredient" 
      ng-options="ingredient._id for ingredient in ingredients" 
    />
    <button 
      type="button" 
      class="btn btn-default btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-remove" 
      ng-click="recipes.currentRecipe.removeRecipeIngredient($index)">
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to display the ingredients listed in the currentRecipe
If I use:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="recipeIngredient._unit">
```

I can see the value of `_unit` showed
But why the select form does not show at all the current value of `recipeIngredient._unit`?

```
 <select 
   class="form-control" 
   ng-model="recipeIngredient._unit" 
   ng-options="unit._id for unit in units" 
 />
```

I've verified the the _unit is part of the list of units
If I change the value of the select box to some value, the input text show "Object", which means the real value of the model is the unit object and not the `unit._id` text

```
ng-options="unit._id for unit in units"`
```

Please tell me if you want additional code

Comment: *Please tell me if you want additional code* --> jsfiddle / plnkr is always good.

Comment: Finally I've found the solution for the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that when I use:

```
ng-options="unit._id for unit in units"
```

The text showed in the drop box is `unit._id`, but the `ng-model` will be the object in unit and not the text showed!
To correct my problem I've written like this:

```
<select ng-model="recipeIngredient._unit" class="form-control">
<option ng-repeat="unit in getId(units, '_id')">{{unit}}</option>
</select>
```

the `getId` is the function that return a list of `_id` from `units`